# How do I add an infinite loop in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, cs50

I have to make this an infinite loop and also make it go back to the start when a wrong character is an input. What to do?

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main ()
{
// Prompt user for input last choice contender
   char c;
   printf("Last choice: ");
   c = getchar();

      // If last choice is R, loser should play S
    if (c == 'R'|| c == 'r')
    {
        printf("Your next move: S");
    }
// Else if last choice is P, loser should play R
    else if (c == 'P' || c == 'p')
    {
        printf("Your next move: R");
    }
// Else if last choice is S, loser should play P
    else if (c == 'S' || c == 's')
    {
        printf("Your next move: P");
    }
// TO DO: If another character start over
    else if (c != 'S'|| c != 's' || c != 'P' || c != 'p' || c != 'R'|| c != 'r')
}
// TODO: make an infinite loop / start over
```

Comment: Have you learned about `while` loops?

Comment: Last `else if` is redundant, we've checked all that before; your condition is wrong too.

Comment: If your loop has a condition "when a wrong character is the input", it is not an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do understand correctly your need, you can do like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main ()
{
    while(true) // or while(1) if you don't want to include stddef or any other lib containing true and false declaration
    // Prompt user for input last choice contender
    {
        char c;
        printf("Last choice: ");
        c = getchar();

        // If last choice is R, loser should play S
        if (c == 'R'|| c == 'r')
        {
            printf("Your next move: S");
        }
        // Else if last choice is P, loser should play R
        else if (c == 'P' || c == 'p')
        {
            printf("Your next move: R");
        }
        // Else if last choice is S, loser should play P
        else if (c == 'S' || c == 's')
        {
            printf("Your next move: P");
        }
        // TO DO: If another character start over
        else if (c != 'S'|| c != 's' || c != 'P' || c != 'p' || c != 'R'|| c != 'r')
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to do anything else for your code to restart at the beginning of the loop if no authorised character have been met. You don't even need to catch them with your latest else if clause, since, arriving at the end of code in the loop anyway, nothing more will be done once arrived there.
(else if (c != 'S'|| c != 's' || c != 'P' || c != 'p' || c != 'R'|| c != 'r'))
But, if you wish to keep your empty (no sub {}) else if clause, you should add a ; at the end of the clause, or else I don't know how you current code would compile.

I welcome you to stack overflow, but I advise you to follow some basic guide on c language, it looks like you are missing some serious basis that will keep blocking you on your current learning road. Overall, I encourage you to pursue your learning :) Good luck !

Comment: In my opinion the best way to express an endless loop is `for (;;) { /*---*/ }`.

Comment: And in mine, it's `while(1)`. Yet both options are correct.

Comment: Both are as good, there is not other reason than chosen norm or personal preference to use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I there are multiple ways of doing this, i recommend a while loop.

Add a while(){

}
around all the code you want to reiterate, inside the while() parameters you can have a boolean like this
boolean won = false,
while(!won)
and add the won = true when a player has won, or when you dont want the player to continue your game!
But i also recommend reading about the while loop, google while loop in google

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to lear, how to write a good answer. As it is right now, your answer is not very clear, because it doesn't use any code blocks, or inline code. Hint: wrap your code in either one or three backticks, \`how to use them\`: `what others see`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an infinite loop (e.g. `for(;;)` or `while(1)`) which will run forever, until an explicit `break` statement is encountered. You can use the `break` statement after determining that the input is valid. Until then, the loop will run forever.

Instead of using a long chain of `if`...`else if`, in this case, you can simply use a `switch` statement, after making the letter upper-case using the function [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop
    {
        //NOTE: The following variable must be an "int" in order to
        //be able to distinguish EOF from an actual character.
        int c;

        printf("Last choice: ");
        c = getchar();

        switch ( toupper( c ) )
        {
            case 'R':
                printf( "Your next move: S" );
                break;
            case 'P':
                printf( "Your next move: R" );
                break;
            case 'S':
                printf( "Your next move: P" );
                break;
            case EOF:
                fprintf( stderr, "unexpected error!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            default:
                printf( "Input was not ok, please try again.\n" );
                continue;
        }

        //input was ok, so we can break out of the infinite loop
        break;
    }
}
```

However, this program does not yet work properly:

```
Last choice: q
Input was not ok, please try again.
Last choice: Input was not ok, please try again.
Last choice:
```

```
Last choice: This is a test.
Input was not ok, please try again.
Last choice: Input was not ok, please try again.
Last choice: Input was not ok, please try again.
Last choice: Your next move: P
```

As you can see, the program prints the error message several times for the same line of input. This is because `getchar` will return every character on the line, including the newline character at the end of the line, and every character will be processed individually, until it finds one of the desired characters. This is not what you want. Since user input is line-based, it would make more sense to read a whole line of input at once, and reject the whole line of input if it contains more than one character (in addition to the newline character). In order to read a whole line of input, I recommend using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop
    {
        //need space for 1 character, the newline character and
        //the terminating null character
        char line[3];

        printf("Last choice: ");

        //attempt to read one line of input
        if ( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that line was not too long
        if ( strchr( line, '\n' ) == NULL )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "Please only enter a single character!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        switch ( toupper( (unsigned char)line[0] ) )
        {
            case 'R':
                printf( "Your next move: S" );
                break;
            case 'P':
                printf( "Your next move: R" );
                break;
            case 'S':
                printf( "Your next move: P" );
                break;
            default:
                printf( "Input was not ok, please try again.\n" );
                continue;
        }

        //input was ok, so we can break out of the infinite loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Now the program works properly:

```
Last choice: This is a test.
Please only enter a single character!
Last choice: q
Input was not ok, please try again.
Last choice: s
Your next move: P
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do want it to run infinite until I hit Ctrl + C. How do I do that?

Comment: @Elisa: The final `break` statement is executed when the input is valid, and will cause the infinite loop to end. If you do not want that, but instead want the infinite loop to continue, then you can simply delete that `break` statement, or replace it with a `continue` statement if you want to be more explicit.

Comment: @Elisa: Most operating systems will automatically cause the program to exit when you press `CTRL-C`. However, it will be an immediate abortive exit, not a graceful exit, unless you explicitly handle the `CTRL-C` signal. This is probably ok in your case, but more complex programs will probably want a graceful exit, so that they have a chance to save all data, before the program exits due to the `CTRL-C` signal.